# IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.0 - Operational Analytics multi-tenancy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

From an existing WL v6.2 infrastructure I used to send analytics data from different runtimes to a single Operational Analytics server, adding a **tenant** parameter in order to treat them separately.

I'm trying to configure in the same way a new MFP v8.0 infrastructure, but I can't get it to work.

Searching the InfoCenter I find documentation about multi-tenancy only up to MFP v7.1, but can't see anything on latest MFP v8.0.

Is **multi-tenancy** still supported in MFP v8 ?
I think yes, because I see that the analytics server still has an **analytics/DEFAULT_Tenant** jndi entry.

However I don't know how to compose the **mfp.analytics.url** jndi entry in the MFP runtime server in order to correctly pass the tenant info to the target analytics server.

I tried something like

```
http://<opan-host>:<opan-port>/analytics-service/rest?tenant=MFPSVIL
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
When I restart the runtime war, in the access log of the analytics web server I see an invalid request coming in e producing an http405 error:

```
[03/Oct/2017:09:59:42 +0200] "POST /analytics-service/rest?tenant=MFPSVIL/v3 HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

What am I doing wrong ?
What is the correct syntax for the **mfp.analytics.url** entry ?

If there is also any doc/wiki/tutorial that I have missed, please let me know.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.
Ciao, Stefano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Multi-tenancy is not supported with MFP Analytics 8.0.
Documentation needs to be updated. That is the reason no where in the documentation support was claimed or the steps for enabling Multi-Tenancy exists in 8.0